# Why does ASP.NET identity need to store external login details?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When we deal with asp.net identity with external authentication such as Google, and with the usage of `IdentityDbContext`, the table below is created by asp.net identity as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] 
(
    [LoginProvider]       NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey]         NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserId]              NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL
);
```

So if an user logs in with Google in the app, ASP.NET identity will prompt the user to a registration page and ask user to register a local account, and this local account will be added as an entry in the following table managed by asp.net identity:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (450)     NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName]   NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail]      NVARCHAR (256)     NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT                NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd]           DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT                NOT NULL
);
```

After user create a local account within the app, there will be one entry in the `AspNetUserLogins` table with the record's `LoginProvider` to be "Google" and `ProviderKey` is the user id in google's end and `UserId` is the foreign key of Id in the `AspNetUsers` table.

But why we need to store those information in `AspNetUserLogins` table? can't we just let the user sign in with external service and if users want to register an local account of the app then prefill some fields and let the user register. And if user doesn't want to register then that's totally fine. Why the user have to register an local account? and if user have to register a local account, then why not get rid of `AspNetUserLogins` table?

Comment: Well, where will security roles, and things like what web pages the user can view? In other words, you can't expect Google to out of their good hearts to keep track of things and rights for that given logon on YOUR site, can you? How you going to control if the user can logon, or even if you decide to disable the logon. Who's going to keep track of that information? It not like google going to spend their time and have THEIR developers work and keep track of things on your site, right?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal currently ASP.NET identity will prompt the user to a registration page and ask user to register a local account after user sign in with external service like Google. In term of security roles or logon disable thing you mentioned, there is another table `AspNetUsers` used by asp.net identity can manage, so the `AspNetUserLogins` table is not needed ? (I also modified the  post to include the `AspNetUsers` table)